# RxJs, Angular4+

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a `film` object and it has a `genre` property.
I want to get films by genre at runtime in custom dropdown `FormControl`.

So I define `new BehaviourSubject(<int>) genre` and if it will change at runtime, get value in `ngOnChanges()` method. And after that it hits API. But I want to check genre value before that. For example if `genre.getValue = 0` don't call the API.

Sample code is below. How can I check value?

```
private _genre;
private selectedGenre = new BehaviorSubject(0);
@Input()
set genre(value: any) {
  this._genre = value;
  this.selectedGenre.next(this._genre);
}
films: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedGenre.distinctUntilChanged().combineLatest(
      this.selectedGenre.distinctUntilChanged(), (_genre) => {
        return {
          genre: _genre
        }
      }
    )
    .switchMap(t => this.service.getFilmsByGenre(genre))
    .subscribe(result => {
      if (result) this.films = result;
    });
}

ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
  if (changes['genre']) {
    this.films = null;
    this.filmCtrl.setValue(null);
    this.selectedGenre.next(changes['genre'].currentValue || 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check it in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Why exactly do you need a `BehaviorSubject` in the first place for this? Isn't the `@Input` property going to be changed somewhere in the Parent Component Template? And when that changes, the `ngOnChanges` will automatically get called.So I'm just not getting why you're using the `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: I'm not expert on RxJs but genre value change on runtime. visitors select a genre from dropdown and films are populated in another dropdown. In onNgInit method I have to track genre input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter to subscribe to only those values which you need to call API.

```
this.selectedGenre.distinctUntilChanged().combineLatest(
      this.selectedGenre.distinctUntilChanged(), (_genre) => {
        return {
          genre: _genre
        }
      }
    )
    .filter(genre=>genre.getValue!==0)
    .switchMap(genre => this.service.getFilmsByGenre(genre))
    .subscribe(result => {
      if (result) this.films = result;
    });
```